# How to dynamically allocate array of 'typedef struct' elements?

Tags: c, dynamic, typedef, allocation

I have this type defined:

```
typedef struct element
{
    uint16_t value_raw;
    float value_scaled;
    char *tag;
    char *id;
    float scale;
} element;
```

I need to declare an array of these types globally for a file, as a few other functions in the same file need to access it. But I won't know the size of the array till I read a configuration file, so I need to dynamically allocate it. I've tried this:

```
element *pv;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int size = findoutthesize();
    pv = malloc(sizeof(element) * size);

    /* and then access the elements like this */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        pv[i].scale = (float) i;
}
```

but it doesn't quite work out the way I expected.... (all the .scale members end up being the same value, which is size-1)

What is the correct way to dynamically allocate an array of type 'element' so I can access the members of each element in the array?

Comment: Your code is right and `scale` is correctly initialized (e.g. see http://ideone.com/0MpJR8). How do you check the value of `scale`?

Comment: It's actually part of a larger file that I didn't want to post here in case I scared anyone off, but I may have obscured the real problem....

https://github.com/eriknyquist/modbus/blob/master/abb_pch550_modbus.c

You can see me attempting to do the same thing on line 293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you have a problem at lines 199 and 200:

```
e.tag = tag; 
e.id = idbuf;
```

`char tag[80]` and `char idbuf[80]` are local variables and as thus the `e.tag` / `e.id` pointers are only valid until the end of the `get_element` function.

Here:

```
for (i = 0; i < modbus_read_count; i++) 
{ 
  pv[i] = get_element(fp, line); 
  printf("tag=%s, id=%s, scale=%.1f\n", pv[i].tag, pv[i].id, pv[i].scale); 
}
```

`pv[i].tag` and `pv[i].id` are [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

You could change your `element` struct to something like:

```
typedef struct element
{
    uint16_t value_raw;
    float value_scaled;
    char tag[80];
    char id[80];
    float scale;
} element;
```

and, inside the `get_element` function, work directly on `e.tag` / `e.id`.